# selenium Select class get return option value empty string

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I would like to use python with selenium to select from a multi-select box. From my code, I am able to open the drop-down list or find the len of options from the box.

But when I just to select the option by `select_by_index`, `select_by_visible_text` or, `select_by_value` I always get error `Message: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated`
and when I just to print the text from the option, I always get the empty string {str}''

The multi-select looks like multi-select section from link https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

My Code

```
e = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('selectName'))
print(e)
print(e.options)
for o in e.options:
    print(o)
    print(o.text)

print(len(e.options))
e.select_by_index(1)
e.select_by_visible_text("A")
e.select_by_value("A")
print(e.all_selected_options)
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

HTML Format:

```
<div class="four wide column">
    <div id="name" role="combobox" aria-busy="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false" class="ui fluid multiple search selection scrolling dropdown">
    <select type="hidden" aria-hidden="true" name="selectName" multiple="">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
    <a class="ui label" value="A"><!-- react-text: 4884 -->A<!-- /react-text --><i aria-hidden="true" class="delete icon"></i></a>
    <input type="text" value="" aria-autocomplete="list" class="search" name="Name-search" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0">
    <div class="text"></div>
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="true" class="selected item"><!-- react-text: 1386 -->A<!-- /react-text --></div>
        <div role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false" class="item"><!-- react-text: 5240 -->B<!-- /react-text --></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Print out Result:

> select.options  [ <
>   selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
>   (session="54c42ae6-e18a-40bb-b497-f2a6b56bc98e", element="12") > , <
>   selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
>   (session="54c42ae6-e18a-40bb-b497-f2a6b56bc98e", element="13") > , <
>   selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
>   (session="54c42ae6-e18a-40bb-b497-f2a6b56bc98e", element="14") > , <
>   selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
>   (session="54c42ae6-e18a-40bb-b497-f2a6b56bc98e", element="15") > ]
>   {str}'' 5

Comment: Check your provided code -- your xpath selector is not valid (typo)? and it would select the div, not the select element, which is also wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change xpath in the select line as below. In your xpath you are using id='selectName' which is associated to div element not to select element.

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='selectName']"))
```